# How to add multiple values accumulatively to specific columns in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I guess this is a tricky question. I want to add some values accumulatively to some specific columns. Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(4,4)
B = np.random.rand(4,4)
[OUT]: A = array([[ 0.46472458,  0.00841153,  0.45631818,  0.42635626],
                  [ 0.37378943,  0.92900513,  0.47074237,  0.1790853 ],
                  [ 0.44455962,  0.38604916,  0.52130988,  0.17871398],
                  [ 0.74742154,  0.48381281,  0.25203475,  0.724025  ]])

[OUT]: B = array([[ 0.78213532,  0.31560444,  0.45251978,  0.19675709],
                  [ 0.06217241,  0.10009086,  0.65308642,  0.95227678],
                  [ 0.65643604,  0.20249389,  0.86545423,  0.62765881],
                  [ 0.61317907,  0.1636594 ,  0.28260492,  0.23835911]])
```

Now I want to add the second row and third row of B to the first column of A, and add the third row of B to the second column of A. Naively I tried this:

```
idx_col = np.array([0,0,1])
idx_row = np.array([1,2,2])
A[:, idx_col] += B[idx_row, :].T
```

But it didn't give me the result I want. The problem is python only adds the third row to the first column and completely ignores the second row to the first column.

```
[OUT]: array([[ 1.12116062,  0.66484757,  0.45631818,  0.42635626],
              [ 0.57628332,  1.13149902,  0.47074237,  0.1790853 ],
              [ 1.31001385,  1.25150339,  0.52130988,  0.17871398],
              [ 1.37508035,  1.11147162,  0.25203475,  0.724025  ]])
```

I realize I can do this with one for-loop, but the thing is I am doing an assignment and it requires the code to be fully vectorized (I know, it's very irritating). Also, this is a toy example, what I am actually implementing is, say A is 500-by-10, B is 500-by-500 and idx_col has a length of 100. So doing each operation separately really doesn't solve the problem. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you need this to be more general, by if you only have 3 operations, why not make each their own line.

```
A[:,0] += B[1,:]
A[:,0] += B[2,:]
A[:,1] += B[2,:]
```

If you need to do this all on one line, it looks like the [numpy function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) `np.add.to` does what you want. The description is as follows

> Performs unbuffered in place operation on operand ‘a’ for elements
>   specified by ‘indices’. For addition ufunc, this method is equivalent
>   to a[indices] += b, except that results are accumulated for elements
>   that are indexed more than once. For example, a[[0,0]] += 1 will only
>   increment the first element once because of buffering, whereas
>   add.at(a, [0,0], 1) will increment the first element twice.

The only issue now is that I cannot determine how to handle multi-dimensional arrays. The documentation suggests it is possible though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I do want it do be more general. I have edited the question to address this point. Also I tried your code, it didn't do the trick either. I don't think it's about the size.

Comment: The transpose is indeed needed, otherwise there would be an error. But still the result is not what it intuitively should be.

Comment: You are correct. Your problem is trickier than initially specified.

Comment: I used a for-loop in the end. Will check if the np.add.to works. Thanks any way!